# flatbuffers include in VS2017 project

Tags: flatbuffers

I have generated a small *.fbs file and included the .h file in my C++ project. I have doubled checked that the flatbuffers.h and flatbuffers.lib are on the include and library paths.

However, when I include the .h file, I get a load of compile errors.

I notice that the following symbol in the included .h file is showing as undefined:

MANUALLY_ALIGNED_STRUCT

I think it is having a problem with this macro:

```
MANUALLY_ALIGNED_STRUCT(4) Vec3 FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS {
```

---

UPDATE

I am now getting builds that complete. I will soon know if it works. But there are this messages at the end of the link:

```
1>Finished pass 2
1>Not launching VCTIP: it is flagged as unstable
1>Win32 API 'CreateFile' failed with 2
1>Not launching VCTIP: it is flagged as unstable
1>Telemetry event upload failed: 'Failed to open connection to VCTIP'
1>LinkWareMessageBus.vcxproj -> D:\Source\LinkWareMessageBus\x64\Debug\LinkWareMessageBus.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: there was commit to change the name of this macro..
https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/commit/eac0bc649029c32576610c811e241155973e6187#diff-e644a513ebf0d4b999ed39c245f8f3db

maybe that was to fix this problem. can you try latest mainline code of flatbuffers and try.

Comment: So it may mean that the `flatc` that compiled your `.h` file, and the `flatbuffers.h` you are including are not from the same version of FlatBuffers.

Comment: I just used the latest distribution. Still get those errors. but it seems to link. Except for the messages at the end (see update).

Comment: It's working. I am not sure this question is worth archiving. I would recommend deleting it. Does anyone mind?